# How can i make monsters drop items when they are being killed

Tags: javascript, software-engineering, html5

I am making HTML 5 game with Javascript i am really new to programming,want to know how to make the enemies drop items after  they are killed when the enemy dies i want the rectangle to represent an item dropped but the rectangle can't be drawn

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script> 
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d"); 
ctx.font = '30px Arial';

var HEIGHT = 500;
var WIDTH = 500;
var timeWhenGameStarted = Date.now();   //return time in ms
var framecount=0;
var player = {
    x:50,
    spdX:75,
    y:450,
    spdY:20,
    name:'P',
    hp:10,
    width:20,
    height:90,
    color:'green',
    Counter:0
};
var upgradelist={};
var enemyList = {};
var bulletList={};
upgrade = function (id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height,color){
    var enemy3 = {
        x:x,
        spdX:spdX,
        y:y,
        spdY:spdY,
        name:'E1T1',
        id:id,
        width:width,
        height:height,
        color:color,

    };
    upgradelist[id] = enemy3;
    }

getDistanceBetweenEntity = function (entity1,entity2){  //return distance (number)
    var vx = entity1.x - entity2.x;
    var vy = entity1.y - entity2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy);
}

testCollisionEntity = function (entity1,entity2){   //return if colliding (true/false)
    var rect1 = {
        x:entity1.x-entity1.width/2,
        y:entity1.y-entity1.height/2,
        width:entity1.width,
        height:entity1.height,
    }
    var rect2 = {
        x:entity2.x-entity2.width/2,
        y:entity2.y-entity2.height/2,
        width:entity2.width,
        height:entity2.height,
    }
    return testCollisionRectRect(rect1,rect2);

}

Enemy = function (id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height){
    var enemy3 = {
        x:x,
        spdX:spdX,
        y:y,
        spdY:spdY,
        name:'E1T1',
        id:id,
        width:width,
        height:height,
        color:'red',

    };
    enemyList[id] = enemy3;
    }

document.onmousemove= function(mouse){
    /*
    var mouseX = mouse.clientX - document.getElementById('ctx').getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var mouseY = mouse.clientY - document.getElementById('ctx').getBoundingClientRect().top;
    player.x=mouseX;
    if(mouseX < player.width/2)
                mouseX = player.width/2;
        if(mouseX > WIDTH-player.width/2)
                mouseX = WIDTH - player.width/2;
        if(mouseY < player.height/2)
                mouseY = player.height/2;
        if(mouseY > HEIGHT - player.height/2)
                mouseY = HEIGHT - player.height/2;

        player.x = mouseX;
    */


}

document.onclick=function(mouse){
    if (player.Counter>5) {
        randomlyGenerateBullet();
        player.Counter=0;
    };
    }

document.onkeydown = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 39)        //d
                player.pressingRight = true;
        else if(event.keyCode === 37) //a
                player.pressingLeft = true;
        else if(event.keyCode === 38) // w
                player.pressingUp = true;
}   
document.onkeyup = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 39)        //d
                player.pressingRight = false;
        else if(event.keyCode === 37) //a
                player.pressingLeft = false;
        else if(event.keyCode === 38) // w
                player.pressingUp = false;}
updatePlayerPosition = function(){
        if(player.pressingRight)
                player.x += 10;
        if(player.pressingLeft)
                player.x -= 10;
      }

updateEntity = function (something){
    updateEntityPosition(something);
    drawEntity(something);
}
updateEntityPosition = function(something){
    something.x += something.spdX;
    something.y += something.spdY;

    if(something.x < 0 || something.x > WIDTH){
        something.spdX = -something.spdX;
    }
    if(something.y < 0 || something.y > HEIGHT){
        something.spdY = -something.spdY;
    }
}

testCollisionRectRect = function(rect1,rect2){
    return rect1.x <= rect2.x+rect2.width 
        && rect2.x <= rect1.x+rect1.width
        && rect1.y <= rect2.y + rect2.height
        && rect2.y <= rect1.y + rect1.height;
}

Bullet = function (id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height){
    var bullet = {
        x:x,
        spdX:spdX,
        y:y,
        spdY:spdY,
        name:'E1T1',
        id:id,
        width:width,
        height:height,
        color:'purple',
        timer:0
    };
    bulletList[id] = bullet;
    };
    randomlyGenerateBullet=function(){
var x=player.x;
var y=player.y;
var height=10;
var width=10;
var id= Math.random();
var angle=Math.random()*360;
var spdX=Math.cos(angle/180*Math.PI)*5;
var spdY=Math.sin(angle*5.180*Math.PI*5);
    Bullet(id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height)};


drawEntity = function(something){
    ctx.save();

    ctx.fillRect(something.x-something.width/2,something.y-something.height/2,something.width,something.height);
    ctx.restore();
}
Newgame=function(){
    framecount=0;
    var timeSurvived = Date.now() - timeWhenGameStarted;

                console.log("You timeWhenGameStarted = Date.now()lost! You survived for " + timeSurvived + " ms.");
                bulletList={ }
                player.hp = 10;
}

update = function(){
    framecount++;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    player.Counter++;


    if (toRemove) {
        delete bulletList[key];
    };

    for(var key in bulletList){
               updateEntity(bulletList[key]);

                var toRemove = false;
                bulletList[key].timer++;
                if(bulletList[key].timer > 25){
                        toRemove = true;
                }

                for(var key2 in enemyList){
                    var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(bulletList[key],enemyList[key2]);
                    upgrade("U1",enemyList[key2],enemyList[key2],0,0,30,30,"gree‌​n"); 
                    updateEntity(upgrade);
                    if(isColliding){
                            toRemove = true;
                                delete enemyList[key2];
                                 break;

                        }        


                }
                    }

                if(toRemove){
                        delete bulletList[key];

                }


    for(var key in enemyList){
        updateEntity(enemyList[key]);

        var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(player,enemyList[key]);
        if(isColliding){
            player.hp = player.hp - 1;
            if(player.hp <= 0){
                Newgame();
            }
        }

    }
    updatePlayerPosition();
    drawEntity(player);
    ctx.fillText(player.hp + " Hp",0,30);
}

Enemy('E1T1',150,450,10,15,30,30);
Enemy('E2T1',250,350,10,-15,20,20);
Enemy('E3T1',250,450,10,-8,40,10);

setInterval(update,40);












</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. There is very little information to go from that you have given us. What have you tried so far? Can you post some code and more specifics of what is going wrong.

Comment: Can you please specify more exactly what problem you are having with adding dropped items to this architecture?  It seems like you already implemented the `Enemy` and `Bullet` entities successfully. So it is not clear why exactly you are unable to also implement the `Item` entity. Please tell us exactly what you have a problem with.

Comment: for(var key in bulletList){
updateEntity(bulletList[key]);
updateEntity(upgrade)
var toRemove = false;
bulletList[key].timer++;
if(bulletList[key].timer > 25){
toRemove = true;
}
for(var key2 in enemyList){
var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(bulletList[key],enemyList[key2]);
upgrade("U1",enemyList[key2],enemyList[key2],0,0,30,30,"green");
 updateEntity(upgrade);
 if(isColliding){
 toRemove = true;
delete enemyList[key2];
 break;
   } }                     
if(toRemove){
delete bulletList[key];
}
 }

Comment: this is what i've tried so far i want to draw a rectangle that represents the item when the enemy dies i used the updateEntity function but nothing happens

Comment: @samantha The code in your 2nd comment is unreadable. When it's not yet in the question, please edit the code into the question to include it.

Comment: @samantha What do you mean with you "used the updateEntity function"? There is nothing in that function which seems to have anything to do with spawning item entities.

Comment: for now i just want to draw a small rectangle to replace the enemy that's why i used the updateEntity function        upgrade("U1",enemyList[key2],enemyList[key2],0,0,30,30,"gree‌​n"); updateEntity(upgrade);

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
 var items = [];

...

function die() //call from wherever.
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numItemsToDrop; i++)
   {
      var item = {}; //if you don't care about type - else use "new Item()"
      item.name = ...; //enter some name here
      item.damage = ...; //etc.
      items.push(item);
   }
}

...

void update() //called every frame to render the world
{
   for (var item in items)
   {
      item.display(); //this is your own function that does whatever it takes to show the item at the correct position etc. on screen.
   }
}
```